# Discord.JS Collector prints without input

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have this code

```js
let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
            filter,
            max: 1,
            time: 10000,
            error: 'time'
        });
let msgcontent = collector.on('collect', m => {
});
collector.on('end', collected =>{
   collected.forEach((value) => {
      console.log(value.content)
      const msgcontent = value.content
   });
});
console.log(msgcontent);
```

and I already get an output without even typing a message. Is the problem that I put the Collector into a constant or is it something else?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: What is being printed when you "already get an output"? The value of `let msgcontent`? You are printing its value at the bottom of the code. That line of code will run immediately after the collector is defined, it will not wait until a message is collected to run. The statement inside your collector `end` handler, on the other hand, can't be printing anything until you send a message or 10 seconds is up. You need to specify what "output" you are getting in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, and as I hinted at in my comment, it seems you are using message collectors wrong. The way your code is defining `let msgcontent` is not how you would go about printing the content of any message that is collected. Do something like this instead:

```js
let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
    filter,
    max: 1,
    time: 10000,
    error: 'time'
});
collector.on('collect', m => {
    let msgcontent = m.content;
    console.log("Message sent:", msgcontent);
});
collector.on('end', collected =>{
   collected.forEach((value) => {
      console.log("Message was collected:", value.content);
      const msgcontent = value.content;
   });
});
```

Basically, the issue was the last line in the code you provided. That line of code doesn't just wait for a message to be collected. It runs immediately after the collector and its event handlers are defined. Whatever value the `collector.on()` method returns by default (most likely something like `EventEmitter` or just `undefined`) was being stored in `msgcontent` and was being immediately printed. This misled you into believing that the collector was collecting/ending before you sent any messages.

So, I made two changes to your code:

**A)** I removed the `let msgcontent` entirely, as that is not how you get messages collected by a collector. The cause of your issue is that you were setting `msgcontent` equal to the output of `collector.on()` and immediately printing it. You confused this with actual collector output; you thought you were seeing the collected message, but you were actually just seeing an unrelated value.
**B)** I labeled your `console.log` statements. This way, you cannot get confused by which statements are being printed at which times.

Other than these issues I fixed in your code that could have potentially misled you into believing the collector was ending without collecting any messages, your collector code appears to be perfect, so I assume what I have described was the issue you were experiencing. And for future reference, please be more specific in your question; specifying what "output" you were getting would have made your question clearer.

### EDIT

Based on your previous comment, it looks like you may want to use [`channel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) instead of a message collector. That will allow you to reference received messages outside the collector, assuming you use `async/await`. Here's an example of how you could do that, based on the code you've provided:

```js
let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages({
    filter,
    max: 1,
    time: 10000
});

// The first and only msg in this case
const msgcontent = collected.first();

// Check if msgcontent is undefined, this means no msgs were collected
if (!msgcontent) {
    // Do whatever code for when nothing is collected in time
    // ...
}
```

Make sure to turn whatever function this code is inside into an `async function`, otherwise the use of `await` won't work. This should be much easier to implement and to read than putting all of your current code inside the collector handlers.

Comment: I made the ```let msgcontent``` because otherwise I couldn't use the received messages outside the collector. So I think if that's the error, I have to write the other code I to the collector

Comment: If you use the collector, you *can't* use the received messages outside the collector. It wasn't built to work like that. You should use [`channel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) instead. I'll edit this answer with an example.

Comment: well that could get difficult since my code is in a while loop, so I would have to put the while loop into an async function for that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your while loop must already be inside a function at some level, since you are referencing `message`. Just make that function `async` by adding the `async` keyword before it. If that isn't going to work for you, you're going to have to put all of your code into the collector as you said in your first comment. Choose whichever one of the options in this answer works best for you. Due to limitations with how these collectors work you *may* need to significantly edit your code either way.